# How can i get Slit Slider to stop after the slides are finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using slit slider (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) for a project and i want the slider to stop after the last slide, while leaving the arrows still active. I'm rather new to jquery coding so if anyone could help it'd really appreciate it. http://jsfiddle.net/totimage/y40wy5uf/

This is the code i'm currently using:

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

    'use strict';

    var $event = $.event,
    $special,
    resizeTimeout;

    $special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
        setup: function() {
            $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
        },
        handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
            // Save the context
            var context = this,
                args = arguments,
                dispatch = function() {
                    // set correct event type
                    event.type = "debouncedresize";
                    $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
                };

            if ( resizeTimeout ) {
                clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
            }

            execAsap ?
                dispatch() :
                resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
        },
        threshold: 20
    };

    // global
    var $window = $( window ),
        $document = $( document ),
        Modernizr = window.Modernizr;

    $.Slitslider = function( options, element ) {

        this.$elWrapper = $( element );
        this._init( options );

    };

    $.Slitslider.defaults = {
        // transitions speed
        speed : 1500,
        // if true the item's slices will also animate the opacity value
        optOpacity : true,
        // amount (%) to translate both slices - adjust as necessary
        translateFactor : 230,
        // maximum possible angle
        maxAngle : 25,
        // maximum possible scale
        maxScale : 2,
        // slideshow on / off
        autoplay : true,
        // keyboard navigation
        keyboard : false,
        // time between transitions
        interval : 500,
        // callbacks
        onBeforeChange : function( slide, idx ) { return true; },
        onAfterChange : function( slide, idx ) { return false; }
    };

    $.Slitslider.prototype = {

        _init : function( options ) {

            // options
            this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slitslider.defaults, options );

            // https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2870
            this.transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            };
            this.transEndEventName = this.transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ];
            // suport for css 3d transforms and css transitions
            this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
            // the slider
            this.$el = this.$elWrapper.children( '.sl-slider' );
            // the slides
            this.$slides = this.$el.children( '.sl-slide' ).hide();
            // total slides
            this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;
            // current slide
            this.current = 0;
            // control if it's animating
            this.isAnimating = false;
            // get container size
            this._getSize();
            // layout
            this._layout();
            // load some events
            this._loadEvents();
            // slideshow
            if( this.options.autoplay ) {

                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // gets the current container width & height
        _getSize : function() {

            this.size = {
                width : this.$elWrapper.outerWidth( true ),
                height : this.$elWrapper.outerHeight( true )
            };

        },
        _layout : function() {

            this.$slideWrapper = $( '<div class="sl-slides-wrapper" />' );

            // wrap the slides
            this.$slides.wrapAll( this.$slideWrapper ).each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    // vertical || horizontal
                    orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

                $slide.addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                      .children()
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' );

            } );

            // set the right size of the slider/slides for the current window size
            this._setSize();
            // show first slide
            this.$slides.eq( this.current ).show();

        },
        _navigate : function( dir, pos ) {

            if( this.isAnimating || this.slidesCount < 2 ) {

                return false;

            }

            this.isAnimating = true;

            var self = this,
                $currentSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current );

            // if position is passed
            if( pos !== undefined ) {

                this.current = pos;

            }
            // if not check the boundaries
            else if( dir === 'next' ) {

                this.current = this.current < this.slidesCount - 1 ? ++this.current : 0;

            }
            else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

                this.current = this.current > 0 ? --this.current : this.slidesCount - 1;

            }

            this.options.onBeforeChange( $currentSlide, this.current );

            // next slide to be shown
            var $nextSlide = this.$slides.eq( this.current ),
                // the slide we want to cut and animate
                $movingSlide = ( dir === 'next' ) ? $currentSlide : $nextSlide,

                // the following are the data attrs set for each slide
                configData = $movingSlide.data(),
                config = {};

            config.orientation = configData.orientation || 'horizontal',
            config.slice1angle = configData.slice1Rotation || 0,
            config.slice1scale = configData.slice1Scale || 1,
            config.slice2angle = configData.slice2Rotation || 0,
            config.slice2scale = configData.slice2Scale || 1;

            this._validateValues( config );

            var cssStyle = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    marginTop : -this.size.height / 2
                } : {
                    marginLeft : -this.size.width / 2
                },
                // default slide's slices style
                resetStyle = {
                    'transform' : 'translate(0%,0%) rotate(0deg) scale(1)',
                    opacity : 1 
                },
                // slice1 style
                slice1Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    'transform' : 'translateY(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
                } : {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice1angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice1scale + ')'
                },
                // slice2 style
                slice2Style = config.orientation === 'horizontal' ? {
                    'transform' : 'translateY(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
                } : {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(' + this.options.translateFactor + '%) rotate(' + config.slice2angle + 'deg) scale(' + config.slice2scale + ')'
                };

            if( this.options.optOpacity ) {

                slice1Style.opacity = 0;
                slice2Style.opacity = 0;

            }

            // we are adding the classes sl-trans-elems and sl-trans-back-elems to the slide that is either coming "next"
            // or going "prev" according to the direction.
            // the idea is to make it more interesting by giving some animations to the respective slide's elements
            //( dir === 'next' ) ? $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' ) : $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

            $currentSlide.removeClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

            var transitionProp = {
                'transition' : 'all ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ease-in-out'
            };

            // add the 2 slices and animate them
            $movingSlide.css( 'z-index', this.slidesCount )
                        .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                        .wrap( $( '<div class="sl-content-slice" />' ).css( transitionProp ) )
                        .parent()
                        .cond(
                            dir === 'prev', 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                this.css( slice1Style );
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    slice.css( resetStyle );

                                }, 50 );

                            }, 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    slice.css( slice1Style );

                                }, 50 );

                            }
                        )
                        .clone()
                        .appendTo( $movingSlide )
                        .cond(
                            dir === 'prev', 
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                this.css( slice2Style );
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    $currentSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-back-elems' );

                                    if( self.support ) {

                                        slice.css( resetStyle ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                            self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                        } );

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    }

                                }, 50 );

                            },
                            function() {

                                var slice = this;
                                setTimeout( function() {

                                    $nextSlide.addClass( 'sl-trans-elems' );

                                    if( self.support ) {

                                        slice.css( slice2Style ).on( self.transEndEventName, function() {

                                            self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                        } );

                                    }
                                    else {

                                        self._onEndNavigate( slice, $currentSlide, dir );

                                    }

                                }, 50 );

                            }
                        )
                        .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                        .css( cssStyle );

            $nextSlide.show();

        },
        _validateValues : function( config ) {

            // OK, so we are restricting the angles and scale values here.
            // This is to avoid the slices wrong sides to be shown.
            // you can adjust these values as you wish but make sure you also ajust the
            // paddings of the slides and also the options.translateFactor value and scale data attrs
            if( config.slice1angle > this.options.maxAngle || config.slice1angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

                config.slice1angle = this.options.maxAngle;

            }
            if( config.slice2angle > this.options.maxAngle  || config.slice2angle < -this.options.maxAngle ) {

                config.slice2angle = this.options.maxAngle;

            }
            if( config.slice1scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice1scale <= 0 ) {

                config.slice1scale = this.options.maxScale;

            }
            if( config.slice2scale > this.options.maxScale || config.slice2scale <= 0 ) {

                config.slice2scale = this.options.maxScale;

            }
            if( config.orientation !== 'vertical' && config.orientation !== 'horizontal' ) {

                config.orientation = 'horizontal'

            }

        },
        _onEndNavigate : function( $slice, $oldSlide, dir ) {

            // reset previous slide's style after next slide is shown
            var $slide = $slice.parent(),
                removeClasses = 'sl-trans-elems sl-trans-back-elems';

            // remove second slide's slice
            $slice.remove();
            // unwrap..
            $slide.css( 'z-index', 1 )
                  .find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' )
                  .unwrap();

            // hide previous current slide
            $oldSlide.hide().removeClass( removeClasses );
            $slide.removeClass( removeClasses );
            // now we can navigate again..
            this.isAnimating = false;
            this.options.onAfterChange( $slide, this.current );

        },
        _setSize : function() {

            // the slider and content wrappers will have the window's width and height
            var cssStyle = {
                width : this.size.width,
                height : this.size.height
            };

            this.$el.css( cssStyle ).find( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).css( cssStyle );

        },
        _loadEvents : function() {

            var self = this;

            $window.on( 'debouncedresize.slitslider', function( event ) {

                // update size values
                self._getSize();
                // set the sizes again
                self._setSize();

            } );

            if ( this.options.keyboard ) {

                $document.on( 'keydown.slitslider', function(e) {

                    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                        arrow = {
                            left: 37,
                            up: 38,
                            right: 39,
                            down: 40
                        };

                    switch (keyCode) {

                        case arrow.left :

                            self._stopSlideshow();
                            self._navigate( 'prev' );
                            break;

                        case arrow.right :

                            self._stopSlideshow();
                            self._navigate( 'next' );
                            break;

                    }

                } );

            }

        },
        _startSlideshow: function() {

            var self = this;

            this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {

                self._navigate( 'next' );

                if ( self.options.autoplay ) {

                    self._startSlideshow();

                }

            }, this.options.interval );

        },
        _stopSlideshow: function() {

            if ( this.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( this.slideshow );
                this.isPlaying = false;
                this.options.autoplay = false;

            }

        },
        _destroy : function( callback ) {

            this.$el.off( '.slitslider' ).removeData( 'slitslider' );
            $window.off( '.slitslider' );
            $document.off( '.slitslider' );
            this.$slides.each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    $content = $slide.find( 'div.sl-content' ).children();

                $content.appendTo( $slide );
                $slide.children( 'div.sl-content-wrapper' ).remove();

            } );
            this.$slides.unwrap( this.$slideWrapper ).hide();
            this.$slides.eq( 0 ).show();
            if( callback ) {

                callback.call();

            }

        },
        // public methos: adds more slides to the slider
        add : function( $slides, callback ) {

            this.$slides = this.$slides.add( $slides );

            var self = this;


            $slides.each( function( i ) {

                var $slide = $( this ),
                    // vertical || horizontal
                    orientation = $slide.data( 'orientation' );

                $slide.hide().addClass( 'sl-slide-' + orientation )
                      .children()
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content-wrapper" />' )
                      .wrapAll( '<div class="sl-content" />' )
                      .end()
                      .appendTo( self.$el.find( 'div.sl-slides-wrapper' ) );

            } );

            this._setSize();

            this.slidesCount = this.$slides.length;

            if ( callback ) {

                callback.call( $items );

            }

        },
        // public method: shows next slide
        next : function() {

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( 'next' );

        },
        // public method: shows previous slide
        previous : function() {

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( 'prev' );

        },
        // public method: goes to a specific slide
        jump : function( pos ) {

            pos -= 1;

            if( pos === this.current || pos >= this.slidesCount || pos < 0 ) {

                return false;

            }

            this._stopSlideshow();
            this._navigate( pos > this.current ? 'next' : 'prev', pos );

        },
        // public method: starts the slideshow
        // any call to next(), previous() or jump() will stop the slideshow
        play : function() {

            if( !this.isPlaying ) {

                this.isPlaying = true;

                this._navigate( 'next' );
                this.options.autoplay = true;
                this._startSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // public method: pauses the slideshow
        pause : function() {

            if( this.isPlaying ) {

                this._stopSlideshow();

            }

        },
        // public method: check if isAnimating is true
        isActive : function() {

            return this.isAnimating;

        },
        // publicc methos: destroys the slicebox instance
        destroy : function( callback ) {

            this._destroy( callback );

        }

    };

    var logError = function( message ) {

        if ( window.console ) {

            window.console.error( message );

        }

    };

    $.fn.slitslider = function( options ) {

        var self = $.data( this, 'slitslider' );

        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

            this.each(function() {

                if ( !self ) {

                    logError( "cannot call methods on slitslider prior to initialization; " +
                    "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                    return;

                }

                if ( !$.isFunction( self[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                    logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for slitslider self" );
                    return;

                }

                self[ options ].apply( self, args );

            });

        } 
        else {

            this.each(function() {

                if ( self ) {

                    self._init();

                }
                else {

                    self = $.data( this, 'slitslider', new $.Slitslider( options, this ) );

                }

            });

        }

        return self;

    };

} )( jQuery, window );
```

Comment: I made a quick jsfiddle of the code, but there's a script inside the actual page that i'm not sure how to introduce in jsfiddle to make it work, so it's pasted above the copyright notice of the js code, maybe someone can make heads of tales of this because i've been trying for two days and can't figure it out. http://jsfiddle.net/nz07s6b1/3/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change the code in `_navigate`, where it says:

```
// if not check the boundaries
else if( dir === 'next' ) {

    this.current = this.current < this.slidesCount - 1 ? ++this.current : 0;

}
else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

    this.current = this.current > 0 ? --this.current : this.slidesCount - 1;

}
```

That's the place that specifies which slide will be the next/previous one (checking if it's the first/last slide), creating the "circular effect". Try changing it so if it's one of the limits, the slide remains the same instead of changing to the next/previous one.

Something like this:

```
// if not check the boundaries
else if( dir === 'next' ) {

    this.current = this.current < this.slidesCount - 1 ? ++this.current : this.slidesCount - 1;

}
else if( dir === 'prev' ) {

    this.current = this.current > 0 ? --this.current : 0;

}
```

That will prevent the circular effect in the slides... but it will create a problem with the animation. To solve the problem with the animation:

1. At the beginning of _navigate add the line `this.prevCurrent = this.current;`
2. After changing the value of this.current (code above), wrap the remaining of the function like this:

   `if (this.prevCurrent != this.current) {
       ....
   } else {
       this.isAnimating = false;
   }`

The arrows will still work, but it will not jump from the last one to the first one (and vice versa). But that's a bit hacky, I would have expected the plug-in to have an option for that.

Comment: Yes, i know it's the first thing i looked for, since it has an auto-play it should normally have an auto-stop but no luck, found nothing on that. The fix above worked to some extent, the navigation shows a change in slides (it has a small nav area below showing which slide is showing and it allows me to go from 1 to 2 and back, but only using the left arrow) but now the slides don't actually animate anymore, they don't change from one to another, only the nav does.

Comment: I don't understand your comment :$ What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested it, but you could extend the plugin to provide that option by saying something like:

```
$.Slitslider.prototype._startSlideshow = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.rotationCount = ++this.rotationCount || 1;
    if((this.rotationCount !== this.slidesCount && this.options.playOnce) || !this.options.playOnce) {
        this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {
            self._navigate( 'next' );
            if ( self.options.autoplay ) {
                self._startSlideshow();
            }
        }, this.options.interval );
    }
};
```

If that code doesn't work, you could try it this way (stops the slideshow, which sets autoplay to false):

```
$.Slitslider.prototype._startSlideshow = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.rotationCount = ++this.rotationCount || 1;
    if(this.rotationCount === this.slidesCount && this.options.playOnce) this._stopSlideshow();
    this.slideshow = setTimeout( function() {
        self._navigate( 'next' );
        if ( self.options.autoplay ) {
            self._startSlideshow();
        }
     }, this.options.interval );
};
```

And that way, you could add an option into your plugin call and say something like:

```
$('div').slitslider({
    autoplay: true,
    playOnce: true
});
```

This code will allow the autoplay to play through once, and if you have the playOnce option set to true, it will stop after it rotates to the last one.

Comment: i tried that, but it breaks the slide entirely. if it's not too much hassle i've added a jsfiddle of the html and css in use maybe that will help explain the problem better?

Comment: What if instead of the if statement wrapping, you say something like `if(this.rotationCount === this.slidesCount && this.options.playOnce) this._stopSlideshow();`?

Comment: either i'm not using it right, or it's not working, i think i'll give up entirely on using this plugin, can't for the life of me figure out how to get the damn thing to stop :( which is sad.

Comment: If you set up a working fiddle, I can help you through it. But if you just need a simple slider, I'd suggest bx slider-- it's pretty awesome and easy.

Comment: I did, it's http://jsfiddle.net/nz07s6b1/3/ but like i said, i'm quite new at this and don't know exactly where to place the onload js script that goes inside the html, so i pasted it in the javascript section right at the top before the start of the copyright notice

Comment: One thing that i did notice is that if i use the navigation (arrows) it actually does stop the slider, basically a side effect of using them is that it does what i need.

Comment: I meant a fully working fiddle so I could try to figure out why that code would mess up the animation... because it should have no effect on the animation at all.